# Spring batch with Spring boot - configuring JobRepositoryFactoryBean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch with Boot. I'm having an issue with configuring jobRepositoryFactory bean with postgres as the database. 
Below is my configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(DataSourceConfiguration.class)
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    private final DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration;

public BatchConfiguration(DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration) {
    this.dataSourceConfiguration = dataSourceConfiguration;
}


    @Bean
    public ElasticReader elasticReader()  {
        return new ElasticReader();
    }

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepositoryFactoryBean() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean fb = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    fb.setDatabaseType("postgres");
    fb.setDataSource(dataSourceConfiguration.dataSource());
    fb.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    return fb.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
    return transactionManager;
}

    @Bean
    public StageReader stageReader(){
        return new StageReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public DocumentItemProcessor processor() {
        return new DocumentItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExcelWiter writer() {
        return new ExcelWiter();
    }

    @Bean
    public StageWriter stageWriter() {
        return new StageWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .next(step2())
                .end()
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<List<JsonObject>,List<JsonObject>> chunk(10)
                .reader(stageReader())
                .writer(stageWriter())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<List<OnboardConfigVO>,List<ExportVO>> chunk(10)
                .reader(elasticReader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

}
```

DataSourceConfiguration.class

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/batch-postgresql.properties")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

@PostConstruct
protected void initialize() {
     ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
 populator.addScript(resourceLoader.getResource(environment.getProperty("bach.schema.script")));



    populator.setContinueOnError(true);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator , dataSource());
}

@Bean(destroyMethod="close")
public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName
       (environment.getProperty(batch.jdbc.driver");
       dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("batch.jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("batch.jdbc.user"));

dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("batch.jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Here is the output of Spring boot App run

```
Using default security password: f5cddd58-4790-427c-83b8-b6c25044db7f

   2017-08-09 09:36:59.589  INFO 42576 --- [           main] 
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: 
 OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant 
 [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant 
 [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant 
[pattern='/error']]], []
   2017-08-09 09:36:59.785  INFO 42576 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9199 (http)
  2017-08-09 09:36:59.790  INFO 42576 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
  2017-08-09 09:36:59.794  INFO 42576 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta 
   data indicating: POSTGRES
  2017-08-09 09:36:59.798  INFO 42576 --- [           main] 
    o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, 
    defaulting to synchronous executor.
```

I have configured the beans in my configuration class. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the issue?  It's connecting to your Postgresql database...

Comment: @MichaelMinella
The issue (I think) is with is INFO warning * 2017-08-09 09:36:59.794  INFO 42576 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta 
   data indicating: POSTGRES*

Comment: So?  You didn't specify the actual db type in your configuration so the metdata figured it out (correctly).  That's really just an info message.  It can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

And replace `fb.setDataSource(dataSourceConfiguration.dataSource());` with `fb.setDataSource(dataSource);`

Comment: I tried autowiring DataSource and using that in **JobRepositoryFactoryBean**, but the output is the same.
I also changed to DriverManagerDataSource from BasicDataSource.

Comment: You can insert a breakpoint into `jobRepositoryFactoryBean()` in order to trace if dataSource has been instantiated or is null in that point.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Michael, this is just an INFO message from Spring Boot and it connects to postgres.