# “No database type set, using meta data indicating: SQLSERVER” Springbatch SQLSERVER

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, maven, spring-batch

I am starting my application with springbatch but it says "No database type set, using meta data indicating: SQLSERVER I have searched the internet and use the same config as many examples in my properties which is the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=FacturaDB
spring.datasource.username=dbnameroot
spring.datasource.password=Testpass123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
IntegratedSecurity = true
```

my pom.xml dependency file is :

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0.jre13-preview</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: And the problem is? That is only an debug/info message not sure what your question is.

Comment: I second @M.Deinum, that is an info message. Since you did not set the database type, Spring Batch tried to detect it from the metadata of the data source (and did it correctly). A similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595978/spring-batch-with-spring-boot-configuring-jobrepositoryfactorybean#comment78321363_45595978